# Google API not compatible with python Celery Tasks?

Tags: django, ssl, google-api, youtube-api, celery

I have a django project, trying to execute some celery workers to perform a task in the background to update my model.  I can execute basic tasks (add .delay()) to end of method in views. ) But can not execute google api calls.  **I can execute the google API calls if it is not a delayed task and it works perfectly and updates my models.  Once I make a .delay() and add to celery queue as a task, I get the ssl error at bottom.**

**Simple task that calls api and prints results: WORKS**

```
@task()
def simple_api_call():
r1=requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
rj1=r1.json()
print(rj1))]
```

**Simple task that calls GOOGLE(youtube) api and prints results: SSL error**

```
@task
def google_api_call()
r1=requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet%2Creplies&allThreadsRelatedToChannelId=UCQMZZMfz0D1RueGzcYLd87Q&searchTerms=love&key=MYKEY')
rj1=r1.json()
print(rj1))]
```

btw you can test out the google api/get the url for the get request here (just unselect the api and oauth:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%22snippet%2Creplies%22%2C%22allThreadsRelatedToChannelId%22%3A%22UCQMZZMfz0D1RueGzcYLd87Q%22%2C%22searchTerms%22%3A%22love%22%7D

SSL error when worker executes the google api call.

```
INFO/MainProcess] Received task: todo.tasks.update_comments[ae9bebfe-4b3c-46ec-b197-0ffa56847f30]

[2019-10-31 05:33:52,652: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task todo.tasks.update_comments[ae9bebfe-4b3c-46ec-b197-0ffa56847f30] raised unexpected: SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=replies%2Csnippet&allThreadsRelatedToChannelId=UC_EyncGJh2QuQHhcfuDWL6g&searchTerms=%23vi&maxResults=100&order=time&key=xxxmyapikey (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(54, 'ECONNRESET')")))'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/tylervanzo/Desktop/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 485, in wrap_socket
cnx.do_handshake()
File "/Users/tylervanzo/Desktop/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1915, in do_handshake
self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
File "/Users/tylervanzo/Desktop/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1639, in _raise_ssl_error
raise SysCallError(errno, errorcode.get(errno))
OpenSSL.SSL.SysCallError: (54, 'ECONNRESET')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/tylervanzo/Desktop/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
chunked=chunked,
File "/Users/tylervanzo/Desktop/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
self._validate_conn(conn)
File "/Users/tylervanzo/Desktop/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 994, in validate_conn
conn.connect()
File "/Users/tylervanzo/Desktop/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 394, in connect
ssl_context=context,
File "/Users/tylervanzo/Desktop/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl.py", line 370, in ssl_wrap_socket
return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
File "/Users/tylervanzo/Desktop/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 491, in wrap_socket
raise ssl.SSLError("bad handshake: %r" % e)
ssl.SSLError: ("bad handshake: SysCallError(54, 'ECONNRESET')",)
```

Using redis as the broker
here are my celery config so far

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'trydjango.wsgi.application'
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0'
BROKER_TRANSPORT = 'redis'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Makassar'
```

Comment: Can you share with us your versions of `requests` `celery` `kombu` `cryptography` -or- `pycrypto`, likely one of those packages is out of date.

Comment: requests==2.22.0   , celery==4.3.0, kombu==4.6.5
cryptography==2.7

Comment: Just checked all are the latest version besides cryptography which just came out with 2.8 a few weeks ago